# Python, why elif keyword?

Tags: python, keyword

I just started Python programming, and I'm wondering about the `elif` keyword.

Other programming languages I've used before use `else if`. Does anyone have an idea why the Python developers added the additional `elif` keyword?

Why not:

```
if a:
    print("a")
else if b:
    print("b")
else:
    print("c")
```

Comment: Check out ruby. It does the same thing. It's not really worth thinking about, IMO.

Comment: Check out perl where it's `elsif`.

Comment: Check out bash/sh where it's `elif` as well.

Comment: If you take the time to look at more programming languages, you'll find that this is really not that strange. What you are experiencing is merely your lack of exposure to programming languages.

Comment: So, you're basically asking why it's called 'elif' rather than 'elseif' or 'else if', right? Not why there is an 'elif' control structure?

Comment: You might be able to find that out by reading the history of Python in mailing lists, or possibly PEP documents. We could always email Guido and hope he answers! Everything else is just speculation.

Comment: Or ask him here on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/users/818274/guido-van-rossum.

Comment: @asmeurer - Learning Guido has an account on SO and works at Dropbox just made my day.

Comment: [Ben's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13096142/1709587) is the most thorough and useful here and deserves to be accepted, IMO.

Comment: @MarkSnidovich: It's `elsif` in Ruby. It's still a weird abbreviation, but it at least begins to sound like `else if`

Comment: Python respects indentation, Else If are two different keywords, That's why it's elif

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Most likely it's syntactic sugar. Like the `Wend` of Visual Basic.

Comment: I'm not sure how this actually addresses the question of why the Python implementers choose `elif` rather than `else if`?

Comment: `elif` is *not* simply a shorthand for `else if`. `else if` actually is a syntax error in both python 2 and python 3.

Comment: @JSQuareD That's true, but just as `elif` was added as a special case, the same could have been done for `else if` without a colon after else.

Answer (score 122):

Far as I know, it's there to avoid excessive indentation. You could write

```
if x < 0:
    print 'Negative'
else:
    if x == 0:
        print 'Zero'
    else:
        print 'Positive'
```

but

```
if x < 0:
    print 'Negative'
elif x == 0:
    print 'Zero'
else:
    print 'Positive'
```

is just so much nicer.

---

Thanks to [ign](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3086/ign) for the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) reference:

> The keyword `elif` is short for 'else if', and is useful to avoid excessive indentation.

Comment: @Adam: what about `else if` where the `else` and `if` are in the same line? I think that is what the OP meant.

Comment: "else if" isn't always a single keyword. For example, in C#, it's just a nested if similar to how I wrote it out in my first example. It's just that C# doesn't care about whitespace as much as python, so it's valid to write out "else if" on one line. As for why it's called "elif" instead of "elseif", "elsif", or anything else, I have no idea. Languages are different and just because some do things one way, doesn't mean everybody has to follow suit. :)

Comment: Just to add a bit more context and source: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: Never realized that `else if` in C could be just `else` and `if`, I always thought of it as one keyword, but this makes much more sense. C is a small language with no fixed style (that's why Python needs an additional `elif`) and it would be strange to use just one keyword with a space in it. Thanks haha!

Comment: This deserves to be the accepted answer imho. My hunch is elif was chosen to keep things nicely aligned (else and elif sharing the same number of characters) and to keep editor column width to a minimum ( the 'else if' keyword taking up plenty more space that the condition could consume) but, again, purely a hunch.

Comment: as for not using 'else if', I think it's a compiler convenience thing. this way the lexer doesn't need to have a look ahead and it's easier to implement using conventional lexical analyzers, 
I don't think there would be a theoretical issue to using "else if" instead of "elif" though.

Answer (score 86):

Languages with C-like syntax get `else if` for free without having to implement it at all.

The reason is that in that syntax control structures simply operate on the next statement, which can be a compound statement enclosed in braces if necessary (e.g. `{ x += 1; y += 1 }`).

This means that once you've implemented `if` and `else`, `else if` just falls out of the grammar of the language naturally for free, with no further implementation effort. To see why, have a look at this:

```
if (condition) {
    if_body();
} else if (another_condition) {
    else_if_body();
} else {
    else_body();
}
```

This looks like an `if` with an `else if` and an `else` attached, each applied to a compound statement. But in fact it's not. This is actually two separate `if` statements, each with exactly one `else` case; the second `if` statement is inside the body of the `else` of the first `if` statement.

`else if { ... }` is really parsed as `else` applied to the next statement, which is an `if` statement (applied to the compound statement `{ else_if_body(); }`. Then the final `else` binds to the immediately preceding `if`, which is the second one.

Here's the same thing written more in line with how it's parsed<sup>1</sup>:

```
if (condition) {
    if_body();
} else {
    if (another_condition) {
        else_if_body();
    } else {
        else_body();
    }
}
```

But it turns out that if the language did directly implement `else if` as a first-class option for `if` statements, it would behave *exactly* the same as the second independent `if` statement inside the `else` of the first! So there's no need to bother implementing `else if` at all; language implementers get `else if` for free with this style of syntax, once they've implemented `if` and `else`.

Python's syntax doesn't allow this freebie.

Programmers of C-style syntax can *think* in terms of `else if` even though the language only has `if` with exactly zero-or-one `else`, but only because they can write code like my first example that is formatted in a way that looks different to a human reader than it does to the compiler.

Python, OTOH, uses indentation to indicate block structure, which forces the block structure to look the same to a human reader as it does to the interpreter<sup>2</sup>. Once you've got `if` and `else` in Python-style syntax, programmers could still write code that *behaves* identically to an else-if, by putting a second `if` statement inside the `else` of a first. But that comes out looking like this:

```
if condition:
    if_body()
else:
    if another_condition:
        else_if_body()
    else:
        else_body()
```

This looks ugly, and is much more complex to think in terms of than an else-if chain once you get more than 1 or 2 else-ifs. So it's worth adding in an explicit language feature to get back the ability to think in terms of else-if. Even though it technically makes the language more complex, it actually makes *thinking* in terms of the language simpler, so it's good complexity; with a manually constructed chain of nested `if`s inside `else`s the reader has to manually read all the code and verify that every `else` except the last contains exactly one `if` statement and nothing else, in order to conclude that the whole sequence is equivalent to a linear chain of conditions checked in order, with some code to execute for the first check that succeeds.

So then. We've seen that languages with C-like syntax might as well go with `else if`, because they get it for free. That's the reason why that exists. Languages with Python-like syntax have to explicitly do something to get a construct that can be used as an else-if. Why did they choose `elif`? It's arbitrary; you'd have to actually ask the people who made the decision.

However Python didn't invent `elif`, it was around in other languages long before Python existed. So I would *guess* that when they had to implement an explicit else-if construct they simply picked one that programmers were already familiar with.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, this is how people who are REALLY serious about always using braces with control structures should write their code. ;)

<sup>2</sup> You can certainly construct counter-examples to this, but it's the general idea of indentation-based syntax.

Comment: For your first footnote: every C style guide ever written says “always uses braces for control structures” and then has a v1.1 where someone scribbled in “except else if”. Every automated formatted or style checker has a v1.1 where the relatively simple parse tree grew an ugly special case for else if. Every “C but better” language starts it’s design requiring braces, then adds the exception, breaking its one-postcard syntax and trivial parser. (Or they just add an elif/elsif/elsei keyword.)

Answer (score 17):

To avoid brace^H^H^H^H^Helse if war.

In C/C++ where you have an `else if`, you can structure your code in many different styles:

```
if (...) {
    ...
} else if (...) {
    ...
}


if (...) {
    ...
} 
else if (...) {
    ...
}

if (...) {
    ...
} else 
if (...) {
    ...
}

// and so on
```

by having an `elif` instead, such war would never happen since there is only one way to write an `elif`. Also, `elif` is much shorter than `else if`.

Comment: the last example is painful to look at.  Woe upon whomsoever inflicted this on you're innocent eyes.

Comment: I cannot understand how an `else if`, if it existed in Python, would lead to a brace war.

Comment: @ypercube: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/386870.html

Comment: @LieRyan You did not answer ypercube's question at all with that link, it is about entirely unrelated topic - it is about the ^H^H^H^H^H expression.

Answer (score 9):

That's just the way it is. [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) uses `else if`, [php](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) uses `elseif`, [perl](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/syntax/ifelsifelse.html) uses `elsif`, the C preprocessor and python use `elif`. None of them are wrong, they just choose slightly different syntax to do the same thing. :D

Comment: It never occurred to me until this answer that C uses `else if` while the CPP uses `elif`, so you often end up with both mixed in a single file.

Answer (score 7):

I find them helpful to help differentiate the "else-if"s from the "final else".

Answer (score -2):

elif is some sort of replacement for switch in other languages but with more power

for example in C you write

```
switch (number){
 case 1:
   doA()
   break;
 case 2:
   doB()
   break;
 case N:
   doN()
   break;
 default:
   doSomethingElse()
   break;
}
```

in Python you write

```
if number == 1: doA()
elif number == 2: doB()
elif number == N: doC()
else: doSomethingElse()
```

As you see `elif` is more powerful since you can put more complex statements than in a switch, plus avoid nesting `if/else` statements

Comment: No, `elif` is the analogue of `else if` in C, which has precisely equivalent power (even though it's implemented with different parsing rules). You can use `else if` instead of `case` even in C. And this certainly has nothing to do with why `elif` is used in python rather than `else if`.

Answer (score -8):

Python inherits this from Perl, where it's called `elsif`.

In Python's case, `else if` as two separate constructs like it is in C-like languages would be quite ugly as you'd have to have `else: if:` with two indenting levels.

It's arguable whether special-casing the two keywords together would be better (so making `else if` a single construct, like the `not in` operator.

PL/SQL also has `elsif`, and the C preprocessor has it spelled `elif`.

Comment: "Python inhertis this from Perl" - Wat?

Comment: I think they both got it from preceding languages - Python is not at all a descendant of Perl.

Comment: `s/Perl/Bash/` would have been better since in bash it really is `elif`. And I believe bash inherited it from sh which is much older than Perl.

Comment: 'elif' was in Algol 68 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68)