# Proper if..else syntax in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, indexing, operand

In my python code, I am attempting to implement an if..else statement. See below:

```
     if index[y] == index[x]:
            continue
            else index[y] != index[x]
                indexdn = indexd
                indadd= index[y]-index[x]
                indexdn[:,y]=indexdn[:,y]+ indadd
                index[y,:]=-indexdn[:,y]
                indexdn[y,y]=0
```

However, no matter how many different ways I attempt to write *else index[x] is not equal to index[y]* I get a syntax error on return of this line. I have tried using else, elif, and for the not operand, != and 'is not'. What is the proper way to write a Python statement using a "not equal" operand so that I do not receive a syntax error?

Comment: Indentation is important in Python, unlike most other languages. The if and else need to be indented at the same level to be valid.

Comment: Have you tried the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html)? Your indexing also looks funky. `if..else` troubles aside, does that part work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
if condition:
    # stuff
elif other:
    # stuff
elif some_other:
    # stuff
else:
    # stuff
```

Note that `else` does not get any explicit condition, it is the catch-all if none of the above conditions were `True`.

Comment: You could add to your answer the difference of using `elif` and `else: if`.

Comment: @heltonbiker There is a good writeup of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742580/python-why-elif-keyword) so I will defer to that

Comment: Yeah, my comment was just to remind the few cases where you actually _want_ nested ifs instead of a single, switch/case-like set of conditions, since they are conceptually different.

Answer (score 2):

Just fix your indentation, change `else` to `elif` and add the missing colon:

```
if index[y] == index[x]:
    continue
elif index[y] != index[x]: # indentation and colon
    indexdn = indexd
    indadd = index[y] - index[x]
    indexdn[:,y] = indexdn[:,y]+ indadd
    index[y,:] = -indexdn[:,y]
    indexdn[y,y] = 0
```

Comment: Also, since both tests are mutually exclusive, the OP could do straigth with an `else`, or even with no additional test at all.

Comment: @heltonbiker And if there are more clauses? What if there's an extra condition. Then unwanted execution will take place.

Comment: @heltonbiker In most cases they *should* be mutually exclusive, but they might not be. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452536/why-does-python-have-an-ne-operator-method-instead-of-just-eq), for example.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing upon 2 important things 1. Intendation and 2. Colon after else

```
if index[y] == index[x]:
    continue
else:
    indexdn = indexd
    indadd= index[y]-index[x]
    indexdn[:,y]=indexdn[:,y]+ indadd
    index[y,:]=-indexdn[:,y]
    indexdn[y,y]=0
```

By going by the example given by you - no comparison is required in the else.

Comment: @Brandon Ginley - please let me know if there is any further scope that you are looking after to implement **`if...else`** in python.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use this in a loop, but if you dont you should use the keyword pass instead continue.

```
if index[y] == index[x]:
    pass
elif: # indentation and colon
    indexdn = indexd
    indadd = index[y] - index[x]
    indexdn[:, y] = indexdn[:, y] + indadd
    index[y, :] = -indexdn[:, y]
    indexdn[y, y] = 0
```

However, if it isn't in loop, you need only:

```
if index[y] != index[x]:
    indexdn = indexd
    indadd = index[y] - index[x]
    indexdn[:, y] = indexdn[:, y] + indadd
    index[y, :] = -indexdn[:, y]
    indexdn[y, y] = 0
```