# When do you use if then else or elif in python

Tags: python-2.7

When im using python on codecademy the tutorials on there use if(): statement then else(): statement. But sometimes it uses if(): then elif(): statement. I dont understand when your suppose to switch them out or which to use first.

```
def fruit_color(fruit):
    if fruit == "apple":
        return "red"
    elif fruit == "banana":
        return "yellow"
    elif fruit == "pear":
        return "green"
```

Comment: Recommend you look at [Control Flow Tools](https://docs.python.org/3.4//tutorial/controlflow.html) in the docs.

Comment: if you have more then 2 possible states you want to check, easy

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Probable duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742580/python-why-elif-keyword

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, why elif keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742580/python-why-elif-keyword)

Answer (score -1):

We could survive in a world in which there was no `elif` statement.  We could do this:

```
def fruit_color(fruit):
    if fruit == "apple":
        color = "red"
    else:
            if fruit == "banana":
                color = "yellow"
            else:
                if fruit == "pear":
                    color = "green"
                # ...
                    # ....
                        # ...
                    # ...
                        # ...
                            # ... --->
    return color
```

but it's rather inconvenient that the nesting keeps increasing and increasing---limited only by the number of types of fruit you want to check, which may be large.   It makes code hard to follow, and in Python it also means the indentation must keep increasing: soon you won't be able to see all your code within the same screen-width.

The `elif` statement solves this inconvenience by allowing you to collapse an `else` followed immediately by an `if` into a single statement that doesn't require an increase in nesting.